# Hard disk periodically hangs with large amounts of I/O

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ntfs, freeze, ddrescue

To illustrate the problem: right now I'm backing up a NTFS partition with `ddrescue`. The application will run for several minutes (2-3 GB) and then apparently hang. No errors are reported and it never changes `successful read: 0 s ago` even though the freeze lasts for minutes. This repeats itself until the process is complete. With this particular disk, the "current rate" (or, the speed of copying at the instant before the freeze) tends to be 90-100 MB/s, while `ddrescue`'s "average rate" (with freezes included) is 33 MB/s.

I've first noticed this while copying very large files or folders in Windows on a thumb drive, as the real disk I/O didn't match the GB remaining figure; later I believed this was an NTFS problem. By now I've had this experience on a multitude of OS's, on multiple computers. Some of the disks that had this were on their deathbed, but it also happens just as often on perfectly healthy disks.

While I still use almost exclusively NTFS, I have a hard time believing this is an NTFS issue when it also affect `ddrescue` with the `-d` flag. So what's behind all this?

Comment: How do you know the read is hanging? If it’s a transfer, you also have the destination to think about. With caching, it would not be uncommon to cache a block of data then wait for it to be written to a device. Especially if it is a USB drive.

Comment: Caching several gigabytes at a time?

Comment: If you see activity on the source or destination drive then your assumptions are incorrect. The data is transferring or the OS is waiting on the disk. You’ve structured your question in a way as to appear it can’t possibly be your equipment, “I’ve had this experience on a multitude of OS’s, on multiple computers.” Yet, a misinterpretation of the data or bad equipment is the only reasonable answer.